# MVC ActionLink adds VS solution name to url

Tags: asp.net-mvc

For some reason when I run my project locally, everything works just fine. When I publish my site live to my shared hosting server, the actionlink causes links to come out as

http// www.mydomain.com/MySolutionName/Account.aspx/LogOn

when it should be

http// www.mydomain.com/Account.aspx/LogOn

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you published to a virtual directory named MySolutionName under the root of the web site.  If you did, then this is expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I thought that this was an option under the Publish screen (or maybe under the Project settings screen). I'm running on my MacBook so I can't confirm. Have you checked there to see?

Can you show some of the ActionLink code that you're talking about...?

Comment: Global.asax
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}.aspx/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" });
            routes.MapRoute("Root", "", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" });

ActionLink Code for login (the link i posted above)
<%= Html.ActionLink("Log On", "LogOn", "Account") %>

Comment: Please edit your original post and put the code there (in a code block), instead of as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

(BTW: I have no idea why this site won't let me log back in. I never got an OpenID when I put in my new user info, wtf?)

I publish to a folder on my desktop and then upload via FTP. On my host I set the folder as an application directory since it's a subfolder of my root.

Root
./MySite
./MyOtherSite

Each folder is it's own application directory where I put different sites. There are no virtual directories that I know of. Since I cant see the server config, i can't be sure of that statement.